# "It's time to pluck a pigeon"

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

Während mir klar ist, was der Satz bedeuten soll, habe ich keine geeignete Weise gefunden den ins Deutsche zu übersetzen (wortwörtlich wäre ja Käse).

Ideen?

---

Edit: Bedeutung ist laut [online enzyklopädie](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Pluck%20A%20Pigeon):

> Pluck a pigeon is slang for to cheat a gullible person out of his
>   money. To fleece a greenhorn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Folgende Redensart trifft es nicht ganz, kommt aber in die Nähe:

> **jemandem etwas/Geld abknöpfen**

([German-English dictionary](http://www.dict.cc/?s=abkn%C3%B6pfen))

Herkunft ([Quelle](http://www.redensarten.net/abknoepfen.html)):

> Das Wort abknöpfen bezieht sich auf den alten Brauch, Knöpfe aus Edelmetallen oder anderen wertvollen Materialien zu verwenden, um seinen (Wohl)Stand zu demonstrieren. Knöpfe waren damals keine Massenware "made in Taiwan", sondern - zumindest für den gehobenen Anspruch - von künstlerisch veranlagten Handwerkern hergestellte Statussymbole.
>
> In ländlichen Gebieten wurden gern - künstlerisch etwas weniger anspruchsvoll - Silbermünzen zu Knöpfen umgearbeitet. Kam es auf einer einsamen Handelsstraße, in einer verwinkelten Gasse oder sonstwo zu einem Überfall - und sicherer als heute war das Leben damals bestimmt nicht - wurde der Kaufmann, Großbauer, Adlige usw. dann nicht nur um Schmuck, Ware oder Bargeld erleichtert, sondern auch um die Knöpfe - sie wurden ihm abgeknöpft.

Besser ist vermutlich

> **jemanden ausnehmen wie eine Weihnachtsgans**

oder

> **jemanden rupfen wie eine Gans**

bedeutet: sich (durch Betrug) an jemandem bereichern; jemanden berauben / ausbeuten; jemanden finanziell übervorteilen, jemanden ausbeuten. ([Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemanden_ausnehmen_wie_eine_Weihnachtsgans))

Comment: Die Version mit der [Weihnachts]gans trifft den Nagel auf den Kopf!